# Should ViewModel be responsible for update/post events?

Tags: ios, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm learning about MVVM-Coordinator pattern and one this is a question mark. ViewModel has the responsibility to fetch and format the data for View to take and just show to the user. Coordinator controls the navigation. Which part should be responsible for post/update events, e.g. performing login/register api methods, performing commment/like requests? Is it also ViewModel's responsibility or a Coordinator's?

This article says coordinator should be responsible for navigation and model mutation: http://khanlou.com/2015/10/coordinators-redux/

But I find examples where ViewModel does the mutation too.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess it’s a bit subjective but I would definitely say View Model. The coordinator is used for navigation, and the models are just objects. 
And as you know, view model is where the business logic belongs.

In my case, I have a dedicated layer of abstraction (Service) where I implement every network service and request. Then my view model just requests the data and sends to the ViewController. I do this because on a Network intensive application, your view models would just have too much code and also because just imagine that you have one view model per view controller and then you need to make the same request on two different scenarios. Will you instantiate the same ViewModel twice for two different view controllers?

Everything is a bit subjective but from my experience, this is the best approach.

Hope that helps.